# Numba nested function returns "Cannot modify readonly array" error

Tags: python, nested, numba

i have this function:

```
@njit
def partial_1dproblem(var,var2,der_array): #First derivative
    y = var
    x = var2
    dydx = der_array
    if y.shape != dydx.shape:
        raise  ValueError('Dependent variable and derivative array have different shapes')
    vardim = var.ndim
    invalid_input = 0
    
    
    #Forward
    
    if vardim == 1:
                
        for i in range(len(dydx)-1):
            dydx[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i])/(x[i+1] - x[i])
            
        i = len(dydx) - 1
        dydx[i] =( (-1/(x[i-2]-x[i]) - 1/(x[i-1]-x[i]))        * y[i] 
                -(x[i-2]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-1]-x[i])) * y[i-1] 
                +(x[i-1]-x[i])/((x[i-1]-x[i-2])*(x[i-2]-x[i])) * y[i-2] )
                                   
    else:
        invalid_input = 1
                        
    if invalid_input == 1:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Input')                
    else:
        return dydx
```

Which calculates a finite difference derivative of an input, the function works when called alone, but returns an error when called inside another function

```
N_points = 10001
der_array_1dproblem = np.empty(N_points)

test_grid_1d = np.linspace(0,N_points-1,N_points)
test_variable_1d = 2*np.linspace(0,N_points-1,N_points)
partial_1dproblem(test_variable_1d,test_grid_1d,der_array_1dproblem)
array([2., 2., 2., ..., 2., 2., 2.])

@njit
def test():
    return partial_1dproblem(test_variable_1d,test_grid_1d,der_array_1dproblem)
test()
Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypeError: Cannot modify value of type readonly array(float64, 1d, C)
```

How can i make it work? I need to call the original function inside another. I tested with some other simple nested functions and it worked, but this one has something that causes this error.

### Solution

As pointed out by @RutgerKassies

```
@njit
def test(der_array):
    return partial_1dproblem(test_variable_1d,test_grid_1d,der_array)
test(der_array_1dproblem)
```

Comment: What happens if you don’t  annotate test()?

Comment: It's because your 2nd function relies on global variables. That's probably best avoided anyway, if you explicitly pass the as arguments it should work fine.

Comment: Global are considered constant in Numba. Actually, modifying global data is a really bad idea in software engineering and they are particularly inefficient (they are expensive in CPython because of a dict fetch and the core developer team refuses to optimize write accesses on them since people should not do that anyway, not to mention it is a plague in parallel computing). A good program should have a main function and no globals except constants. Modifying globals is just fine for short scripts in an interactive interpreter.

Comment: @RutgerKassies how can I do that? Because the global variable in the inner function is der_array, but it's already a parameter, hence why it works in isolation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard according to the numba docs if you pass the global as an argument it should work fine, and indeed it does, when the function is alone. However when inside another, it returns an error.

Comment: @FrankYellin The outer function runs fine without the decorator, however, the actual outer function i am trying to run does a lot more, and i need the performance...

Comment: @Klaus3 It's indeed a parameter to your inner function, but that isn't the function that's failing (proofing the point). It's your test function that fails because `def test()`, just add any arguments there as well and pass them along. It might feel redundant, but keep in mind that Numba doesn't execute in the Python namespace (which is why it's useful ;)).

Comment: @RutgerKassies Gotcha, it worked, i will update in the question